# Como realizar uma função no template no componente <kendo-tabstrip-tab>

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui

Tenho um componente no qual uma parte deste componente possui essa parte:

```
  <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'Categoria'" [disabled]="ReferenciaMktId == '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'" [selected]="false">
    <ng-template kendoTabContent (click)="carregaCategorias()">
      <div class=' w-100'>
        <form [formGroup]="formGroup">
          <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center my-2">
            <h5>Cadastro Geral da referência</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mx-3">
            <div *ngIf="formGroup.invalid" class="error-msg">
              <div *ngIf="formGroup.touched" class="text-danger"><small>*Os
                  Campos em destaque são obrigatórios</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
```

Preciso que co clicar no componente kendo-tabstrip-tab eu chame umaa determinada função, porém nada parece funcionar.

O que eu tentei:

```
  <kendo-tabstrip-tab (click)="teste()" [title]="'Categoria'" [disabled]="ReferenciaMktId == '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'" [selected]="false">
```

também tentei:

```
  <kendo-tabstrip-tab (change)="teste()" [title]="'Categoria'" [disabled]="ReferenciaMktId == '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'" [selected]="false">
```

TS:

```
teste(){
    console.log('entrou')
  }
```

Ao clicar no elemento nada é mostrado no console.

Answer (score -1):

**Ola,**

Este componente que você está usando tem um método que pega o click, olhando a documentação acredito que seja (tabSelect), você pode substituir a função de (click) por está função (tabSelect), você terá o mesmo resultado. Ficar assim: **(tabSelect)="teste()"**.

**Obs:** Quando utilizamos bibliotecas prontas normalmente elas tem as formas especificas de fazer algumas funções básicas como está, por isso o (click) não funcionou. Neste link tem um exemplo: [exemplo de uso](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/layout/tabstrip/#toc-basic-usage)

Comment: Na verdade esse método tabSelect é um evento apenas do kendo-tabstrip. No site quando você clica "API Reference of the TabStripTab Component" você é redirecionado para o kendo-tabstrip. Eu tentei usar o tabSelect no tabstrip-tab, mas ele é realmente um evento exclusivo do kendo-tabstrip. Eu tive que usar o ngChange nesse caso.